# Enabling and disabling a form depending the value of a select

Tags: jquery, forms

I have this example simple code to enable and disable a form according to a select elements value.

```
$("#myoptions").change(function(){
    var item = $("#myoptions option:selected").val();
    $("#target").html(item );
    if(item == "empty"){
         $("#addForm").children().attr("disabled","disabled");
        /*else{
         $("#addForm").children().removeAttr("disabled");
        } */           
    }
});
```

The problem is it can be disabled but when trying to enable again it doesn't work and prevents the code from executing.

The enabling code is commented have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/BbZw8/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` statement was inside the `if` statement - the problem was simply due to an incorrectly placed closing brace. Other than that the code worked.

Try this:

```
$("#myoptions").prepend("<option value='empty'>choose item</option>");
$("#myoptions option:first").attr("selected", "selected");


$("#myoptions").change(function() {
    var item = $("#myoptions option:selected").val();
    $("#target").html(item);

    if (item == "empty") {
        $("#addForm").children().attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
        $("#addForm").children().removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/BbZw8/4/)

Comment: thanks and very sorry for that :D
now let me show the bigger code
link will be updated in a minute